# Checking PHP script running in process

Tags: php

```
ps ax | grep -i 'php complete.php'

<?php
exec("ps ax | grep -i 'php complete.php'", $pids);
if(!empty($pids)) {
die("already running");
}
```

I went to check my ps ax, but din't saw the complete.php , and I went check a folder which will output something if complete.php is running, but nothing output.

It giving me a false positive. how do I check if the script complete.php is currently running.

Reason is because I want it to run synchronously and I had a endless loop execute complete.php every 2 minutes acting like a cron job.

Comment: `grep -i php complete.php` will be in the processlist, creating a false positive. Quick & dirty solution is a `grep -i php [c]omplete.php` (just add `[]`'s around one character of your choosing), but a more robust solution is usually working with something like pid files. If you want to run it & keep running it, something like `supervisor` would help you keep it up, otherwise, it depends on whether your system uses sysvinit / systemd / upstart et al. what the best course of action is.

Comment: Check what does `exec('ps ax', $o);print_r($o);` return in PHP. Are the lines cut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd only see the php process running. My approach for seeing a php process running is to alias the php binary and run it with that.

ln -s /usr/bin/php longrunningphp

longrunningphp /path/to/your/script

Then check with ps ax | grep longrunningphp

Answer (score 0):

[I had the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7468000/67332) When running in the console, you will get the result, but when the same command is used in the PHP, nothing would be returned. The problem lies somewhere in terminal width that is allowed for PHP. Simple solution would be to increase it. Example:

```php
exec("export COLUMNS=1000; ps ax | grep -i 'php complete.php'", $pids);
```

```
COLUMNS
    Used by the select command to determine the terminal width when printing 
    selection lists. Automatically set upon receipt of a SIGWINCH.
```